# Steam Authenticator doesn't load the page properly

Tags: steam, steam-mobile

My steam mobile authenticator isn't really working. It looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure why the screen is mostly white and why it doesn't allow me to accept the sell order.

Comment: This looks like a connection or server issue.

Comment: Since it says "View Mobile Website" I'm assuming you are looking at the desktop version of the site instead of the mobile one on your phone.  Try either viewing the mobile website, or changing your browser settings to request the mobile site instead of desktop.

Answer (score 1):

Good afternoon Daniel!

Your error seems to a be connection or server issue as dly mentioned before me. It mainly looks like the css and/or the javascript part of the page is not available.
This error can be at 3 locations (at least according to my experience, but I'm always open to new ideas and suggestions):

1. The server is not generating it due to an error on their side. In this case you can either wait for them to repair it or write to steam support (more details here: https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=1223-qroc-4460)
2. There is some connection issues. You can test it out with trying on a different network than before. (Try wifi network or a different internet source then before, for example; if it was not working though the school network, try it on your home network etc.)
3. A cache or app error. The first can be checked with emptying the cache (Try at your own risk; see expalation later) for the app (On Andoid 6: Settings-> General -> Apps -> Steam Authenticator -> Storage -> Clear Cache). A similar error like yours with this as solution: https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/1/412448792359440587/  BE VERY CAREFULL with this step though! If you accidentally delete the data of the app, than you will lock yourself out from Steam, and it can be a really long process to get it back. I repeat do NOT delete the data. (I once lost access to a different service due to a similar mistake, don't be like me :'D) The second (app error): there isn't much you can do about it, you
   can either wait or write to their support.

Some info that might help with finding the error: Was there anything special when it happened? (new network, app update, system update, etc). Is the error still there after restarting the app/phone? How long has this error been there?

Best wishes, I hope I could help!